# Formulae created in Excel not working in OpenOffice

Tags: openoffice.org, microsoft-office

I am trying to open some Microsoft Office files in which there are formulae which are apparently copy pasted and therefore can be separated from the written rest. The problem is, these formulae don't seem to exist with OpenOffice, any suggestions?

Comment: Which functions are you having problems with?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Specifically, my issues were due to sum.product not being supported (or well supported) by openoffice. Please note this was Spanish version, but I guess it might happen in some others, too... I changed to LibreOffice and everything is going fine now.